# delete specific keyword from a comma separated string in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to delete image name from database which is in comma separated form

I used below approach..

names is in database : 31.jpg,31 copy.jpg,110 copy.jpg,110.jpg,110 copy-1.jpg,

After explode it :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 31.jpg
    [1] => 31 copy.jpg
    [2] => 110 copy.jpg
    [3] => 110.jpg
    [4] => 110 copy-1.jpg
    [5] => 
)
```

To delete img name with comma : 110.jpg,

Now result : 31 copy.jpg,110 copy.jpg,110.jpg,110 copy-1.jpg,

But why is `110.jpg` in result?

Code for above approach.

```
<?php

    require("include/config.inc.php");

    $parent_img_id = 184;
    $child_imgs_id = 1221;
    $delimg = '110.jpg';

    $getInfoChild_imgs = mysql_query("select * from parent where parent_img_id = '$parent_img_id' and child_imgs_id = '$child_imgs_id' and child_imgs like '%$delimg%'") or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($getInfoChild_imgs)>0){
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($getInfoChild_imgs);

            $child_imgs_name =$result['child_imgs'];
            $child_imgs_name = explode(',', $child_imgs_name); // Explode into array


            $deleteImgName = $delimg.',';

            unset($child_imgs_name[ array_search($deleteImgName, $child_imgs_name) ]);

            $child_imgs_name = implode(',',$child_imgs_name); 

     }
?>
```

Comment: And the Question is ...?

Comment: this is why you dont store data like this = db normilisation

Comment: @dognose : But why is "110.jpg," in result.

Comment: [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: thankx all of you. y prob is solved..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$deleteImgName` is `110.jpg,`

The array doesn't have `110.jpg,`. It has `110.jpg`

When you explode using `,`, the elements don't contain any commas.

Change `$deleteImgName = $delimg.','` to `$deleteImgName = $delimg;`,

Comment: Also, be warned that if the name doesn't exist for X reason, you should probably validate it first.  if (in_array($deleteImgName, $child_imgs_name)) {
        unset($sheetData[array_search($deleteImgName], $child_imgs_name)]);
    }

Answer (score 1):

remove the comma from the delete image variable. I haven't checked but since you exploded the commas they will be gone from the array

```
$deleteImgName = $delimg; #.',';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `$deleteImgName` where you appended a "," that is not part of the array entry after exploding the string.